# how to check the end of the line in the ANTLR parser rule even if the new line character is sent to hidden channel

Tags: antlr, token, hidden, analysis

I have 3 statements as follows

1) IF a==b THEN print(a);

2) IF a==b THEN /* Action block follows */

3) IF a==b THEN

how can I differentiate between these statements using ANTLR parser rule

I'm using a rule like

```
if_stmt : IF_T LITERAL_T '==' LITERAL_T THEN_T
{
   /* My java code goes here*/
}
```

I would like to maintain the rule as same and differentiate in the action block of the rule

Note : new line character and comment goes to hidden channel

Comment: In the second case, what came after "THEN" is just a comment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not put all the "intelligence" into the parser itself. It might get over complicated very quickly. You can either traverse the AST (maybe using treewalker) and check if `getLineNumber()` for if statement returns the same value as for the first statement in the then block.

You can also put similar condition into the if_stmt rule action.

Comment: Can I look-ahead for the hidden tokens using java code? If it is possible, could you tell me how to do it....